# Azure CLI Task Yaml

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-cli2, inline-scripting

I am trying to execute Get-AzSqlServer from AzureCli@2 yaml pipeline and it is throwing an error:
The term 'Get-AzSqlServer ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Here is my task

```
- task: AzureCli@2
  inputs:
   azureSubscription: 'serviceconnection'
   scriptType: 'ps'
   scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
   inlineScript: |
    $sqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName rgTest
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `AzurePowerShell@5` if you want to run PowerShell in an authenticated session.

You could also try running `Import-Module` for the appropriate Azure PowerShell modules, but I don't guarantee that would work.

Comment: I am trying this - task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
   azureSubscription: 'serviceconnection'
   ScriptType: InlineScript
   azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
   Inline: |
    $sqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName rgTest

Comment: Sorry missed adding, before the $sqlServer I also have Install-Module Az.Sql

Comment: AzurePowershell@5 also fails with same issue unfortunately

Comment: Are you using a private agent or the Microsoft hosted agent? If you're using a private agent, you *absolutely* need to install the module first.

Comment: Private and I did try to install az.sql

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
   pwsh: |    
     $sqlServer = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName rgTest
```

Comment: Do you mean no changes to scriptType or task? Just pwsh instead of inlineScript?